# I can't convert this String to Date

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I want convert "Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2018" to "2018-01-18" -> yyyy-mm-dd.

But I get error -> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2018".

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

    stringValue =  String.valueOf(cell.getDateCellValue());
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(stringValue);
    System.out.println(date);        
   break;
   case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:... 
   break;
}
```

Maybe is why I have `cell.getCellType()` and `Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` deprecated ?

Comment: Side note: "Jan 18 2018" won't result in "2018-01-01" :)

Comment: 2018-01-18 XDDD

Comment: You’re overcomplicating it. Assuming you are uing Apache POI, `cell.getDateCellValue()` is already returning you a `java.util.Date`. Then your code converts that into a `String` and tries to convert it back into a `Date`. No reason to do that.

Comment: The `Date` class is not only long outdated, it also has a range of design problems with it. While I don’t think there’s a POI version that can give you something better, I suggest you do `Instant inst = cell.getDateCellValue().toInstant();` and use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) from that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `Locale` is not in this format, try `Locale.US`, and you need use `x` for timezone, try:

```
String input = "Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2018";

DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss x yyyy", Locale.US);
Date date = parser.parse(input); // parse String to Date

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); // format Date to String
```

Or you can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) since java8:

```
String input = "Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2018";

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(input,
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US));

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(zonedDateTime.toLocalDate()));
```

Comment: System.out.println(date);      --->>  Thu Jan 18 00:00:00 CET 2018 xDD

Comment: @EduBw You need two `SimpleDateFormat`, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a locale, then JVM will use the default locale of the system. If that also happens to be US English (or some other language where the abbreviation for January is "Jan"), then the results will be the same.
Please take a look at this thread : https://coderanch.com/t/491599/java/SimpleDateFormat-locale